# Adding .swf type splash screen for Android using ionic2/cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic2

How do i add splash screen for '**.swf**' type file using ionic2/cordova. I tried to add but i am getting error saying '**only supported formats are .png or .xml**'

```
<splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.swf" />
<splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.swf" />
<splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.swf" />
```

Comment: yes please use png only as they give in their doc only support .png

Comment: @Naitik, but i m looking animation kind of image. Could u please suggest some other approach

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

swg or gif animations are not supported on Android. Animations are possible using jQuery. This is what you can do,

First of all hide splash screen otr put blank then set your animatesd splash screen with following steps.

1. Create a **data-role="page"** div which contains your splash screen view
2. register a event listener for "pageshow" event for this page and start your animation using jQuery
3. In the same eventlistener call javascript's timeout function

> ```
> setTimeout('functionToLoadNewPage', 2000); 
> //functionToLoadNewPage - function name which will load a new page using
>
> $.mobile.changePage and 2000
> ```

**2000** is number of milliseconds for splash screen to be visible

**OR**

In webview .gif works well. In other cases it does not work in android. You need to customize android java code to make it work. But their is an alternative.

If you have the images for all frames (you may also extract them from gif) and use android animation on the images. It will look like gif image only. All i mean is that you can do frame anmations.

This link will give you some idea:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-creating-frame-animations/

You may google more to find better tutorial. This kind animation works very well.

For IONIC-1 support you can do like [this](http://www.gajotres.net/using-views-events-to-create-javascript-pure-ionic-splash-screen/),  and [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wlttul?p=preview) for this

Comment: Thanks @Naitik. But i am using ionic2/angular2  for developing mobile apps. is there any approach using this technologies to add this type of splash screens?

Comment: it's not for ionic 2 but it's ionic one please try http://plnkr.co/edit/Wlttul?p=preview

Comment: Thnaks u r answer.. i will try it.